# Java FRANCE/FRENCH Locale thousands separator looks like space but not actually

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting

If I convert a number in FRANCE/FRENCH locale it should use space as thousands separator. If I try to replace the spaces with some other characters, it does not find any space.

```
String input = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(123123123);
System.out.println("String after conversion in locale "+input);
input = input.replace(" ", ".");
System.out.println("After replace space with dot      "+input);
```

OUTPUT

```
String after conversion in locale 123 123 123
After replace space with dot      123 123 123
```

So though separator looks like space it is something different. What is the exact character ? How can I specify that character in input.replace() so that I can replace it with dot ?

Comment: Why not set up a number formatter that uses a dot?

Comment: @mlk my code receives FRANCE formatted string. I want to convert it. So this code is just show whole flow.

Comment: I would be very tempted to convert it to a number (as that is what you are working with) then convert it back to a string in the format that you want it rather than do string manipulation. It feels too close to the anti pattern of using Strings when objects would make more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by [**Joop Eggen**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen) in his answer It is `\u00a0` the non-breaking space.

As a work around, I got the thousand separator as follows

```
String input = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(123123123);
System.out.println("String after conversion in locale "+input);

DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
char thousandSep = symbols.getGroupingSeparator();

input = input.replace(thousandSep, '.');
```

It worked as expected

```
String after conversion in locale 123 123 123
After replace space with dot      123.123.123
```

Comment: Note in JDK13+ the non-breaking space in CLDR has changed from `\u00a0` to `\u202f` https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8274768

Answer (score 14):

It is `\u00a0` the non-breaking space, which makes sense for an amount. *(Imagine € 40 at the end of a line, and the next starting with 000.)* The same holds for some other languages.

```
input = input.replace('\u00a0', '.');
```