# How to format a number for european language

Tags: java, android, numberformatter

I have a Double: 5096,54
I need to format it as : 5.096,54 (european format for currency)
I'm trying with this code without any success.

```
 Locale l = Locale.getDefault(); // ("fr" in my case)
 // Get the formatter for the specific locale
 NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(l);

 // Always 2 decimals
 formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
 formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

 // Format
 return formatter.format(d);
```

Output: 5 096,54 when I'm expecting 5.096,54 
Any idea why it fails?

Comment: most european formats is space as thousands separator and coma as decimal separator ... but you can try Italian or Norwegian  locale

Comment: http://ideone.com/IHc6ID https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Comment: Thanks all for the help, the confusion comes from the fact the Locale "fr", is FRENCH (and the output is e.g.: 5 096,54) but in Belgium, french it is supposed to be 5.096,54. So, setting up my Locale to 'Locale l = new Locale("fr", "BE");' did fix my issue

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me with Spanish locale:

```
    Double d = 5096.54;

    Locale l = Locale.getDefault(); 

    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(l);

    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    String d1 = formatter.format(d);
```

Result: 5.096,54

It seems the French locale use something that looks like a space as a thousands-separator, you can check this question:

[Java FRANCE/FRENCH Locale thousands separator looks like space but not actually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495434/java-france-french-locale-thousands-separator-looks-like-space-but-not-actually)

They fix it with this workaround:

```
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = df.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
char thousandSep = symbols.getGroupingSeparator();

input =input.replace(thousandSep, '.');
```

You can either use the same workaround or use the Spanish Locale (or any other that matches with your needs)

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(l);

DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); // setting the thousand separator
// symbols.setDecimalSeparator(','); optionally setting the decimal separator

formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

String formattedString = formatter.format(yourDouble);
```